# Where can I find the device model for Google Play Developer Console: Crashes & ANRs?

Tags: android

I recall seeing a check box on android apps that, when crashing, will ask to send the device data with the crash report.

My app has produced a handful of `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` on my customers devices, and I was wanting to see the model phone they are using to see if I can create an alternative for their below average hardware. Or if nothing else, disallow their model from being able to download the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless it says on the report (because the device sent that data), the only other place is in the message the user sent with the error report.

---

**If neither of those two places then you cannot determine it for now.** However if you then know which bit of your code is causing the error you could wrap the code in a try catch and rethrow it with the device type. This would only benefit you you in the future and not for the current reports. Like this:

```
try{
   myVar.methodThatCausesCrash():
} catch (OutOfMemoryException e){
  throw new Exception("OutOfMemoryException model: " + Build.MODEL, e); // or rethrow another OoME
}
```